# Handling Net::HTTP.get failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, httpwebrequest

The following line:

```
page_source = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://not-a-real-url.com"))
```

When passed a url that is properly formatted, but doesn't go anywhere (like the example above), dies out with:

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I'm trying to figure out how to "begin / rescue" this condition, but I can't seem to find in the documentation what error, if any, the 'get' method is throwing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this help?

```
begin
  page_source = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://not-a-real-url.com"))
rescue SocketError => e
  puts e.message
end
```

Comment: I tried this for my issue but the `=>` seems to throw an error as rails seems to think you are trying to close the ruby tag <%= begin
  page_source = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://not-a-real-url.com"))
rescue SocketError => e
  puts e.message
end %>